# Combinatorics(Invariance)

Tags: combinatorics

The numbers 1, 2,..... ,20 are written on a blackboard. It is permitted
to erase any two numbers a and b and write the new number ab + a + b. Which
number can be on the blackboard after 19 such operations?

I spent almost 45 minutes on this. Initially I got an idea due to the fact that (a+1)(b+1)=ab+a+b-1.I tried to find some invariant with this but ultimately didn't find any.

Comment: You are on the right track. If $a,b$ are the old numbers and $c$ is the new number then $(a+1)(b+1)=c+1$. It means that what function of the numbers of the blackboard remains invariant?

Comment: Thanks A Lot !!